# A differential equation $f'' - af+b=0$ (symmetric vs asymmetric conditions)

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The solution to

$$\frac{d^2f}{dx^2} - \frac{f-f_0}{L_a^2} +c=0$$

with $x$-coordinate set to zero at the middle of $-L/2<x<L/2$ and symmetric initial conditions $f(\pm L/2)=f_0$ looks nice as follows:

$$ f(x)=f_0+L_a^2c\left(1-\frac{\cosh(x/L_a)}{\cosh(L/2L_a)}\right) \ \ \ \ \ \ \  -L/2<x<L/2$$

I do not understand how $L$ comes to the picture? A nice solution would be appreciated.

$$ \\ $$

I am also wondering what the solution looks like when conditions are asymmetric $f(-L/2)=f_1$, $f(+L/2)=f_2$ $(f_1 \neq f_2)$.
You may change $-L/2<x<L/2$ to $0<x<L$ with $f(0)=f_1$, $f(L)=f_2$ if more convenient.

Comment: Any thoughts about my answer, Jake?

Comment: Earth to Jake – come in, please.

Comment: By shifting the function value $g:=f-b/a$, the equation becomes $g''-ag=0$, the solution of which is well-known. What more do you want ?

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to $f''-a^2f+b=0$ is $f(x)=Ce^{ax}+De^{-ax}+ba^{-2}$, where $C$ and $D$ are arbitrary constants. It's a little neater to write this as $$f(x)=E\cosh(ax)+F\sinh(ax)+ba^{-2}$$ where $E$ and $F$ are arbitrary constants. With a little bit of algebra, you can express $E$ and $F$ in terms of $C$ and $D$, or vice versa.

Now both $\cosh(ax)$ and $ba^{-2}$ are even functions, while $\sinh(ax)$ is an odd function (I'm assuming throughout that $a\ne0$), so if you have initial conditions $f(\pm r)=s$ then $F=0$ and $s=E\cosh(ar)+ba^{-2}$ from which you can get $E=(s-ba^{-2})/\cosh(ar)$ and thus $$f(x)={(s-ba^{-2})\cosh(ax)\over\cosh(ar)}+ba^{-2}$$

If instead your initial conditions are $f(0)=m$, $f(c)=n$, then you get the two linear equations $C+D+ba^{-2}=m$, $e^{ac}C+e^{-ac}D+ba^{-2}=n$, and you can solve this pair of equations for the unknowns $C$ and $D$.